# Ancor referer javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, referer

So I have a page with two ancor elements that link to the same page. I want to know which of the two ancors was clicked when the second page loads with javascript in order to initiate different actions. I know that document.referer exists and that it gives me the uri from where the user came, but i want to know what element he clicked.

thanks!

Comment: Maybe add a different [query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/search) to the hrefs of the anchors?

Comment: Good idea and exactly what I needed. thanks!